# How can I realize key constraints in clingo？

Tags: logic, clingo

I'm now learning prolog and try to use clingo to model key constraints but have met some troubles, hope someone can give me a hand. Here are my problems:

1. I want to build a key constraint and write something like the following in clingo

```
:-stu(X,Y1,Y2),stu(X,Z1,Z2),not(Y1=Z1,Y2=Z2).
```

as an integrity constraint but get a syntax error. I tried another way to put it and it seemed to work.

```
Y1=Z1:-stu(X,Y1,Y2),stu(X,Z1,Z2).
Y2=Z2:-stu(X,Y1,Y2),stu(X,Z1,Z2).
```

But still I wonder if I can put the seperated constraints together into just one key constraint so to make the program more concise?

2. Another problem is about how to build fact 'there exists something' in clingo, what I want to achieve is to use clingo to judge if two given sets of rules are satisfiable or not, and here is an example.

The first set of rules says that "there exists a student whose id is 1 and name is mike":

[image]

and "two students with the same id should have the same name and age" (which is a key constraint):

[image]

So I write the first set of rules in Clingo as:

```
stu(1,"mike",v).
:-stu(X,Y1,Y2),stu(X,Z1,Z2),(Y1,Y2)!=(Z1,Z2).
```

Suppose the second set of rules is given which says that "there exists a student whose id is 1 and age is 27":

[image]

and the second set of rules is written in Clingo as:

```
stu(1,v,27).
```

My problem is that if simply put these two sets of rules in a program, Clingo will judge that they can not be satisfiable cause ("mike",v) != (v, 27). So there must be something wrong with my solution (probably with the way to build existence), because the two sets of rules are actually satisfiable if you have a student with id = 1, name = "mike" and age = 27. I wonder if there is a way to use Clingo to judge satisfiability of two sets of rules like mentioned above, thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify what is a key constraint and what is the expected result/error you get ?
Could you also maybe reread and rephrase some sentences as they are sometimes hard to understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post an integrity constraint using a tuple comparison

```
:-stu(X,Y1,Y2),stu(X,Z1,Z2), (Y1,Z2)!=(Z1,Z2).
```

is probably what you want to write.

A rule like

```
Y1=Z1:-stu(X,Y1,Y2),stu(X,Z1,Z2).
```

is equivalent to

```
:-stu(X,Y1,Y2),stu(X,Z1,Z2), Y1!=Z1.
```

To answer your second question:

Seperate the age and the name into two predicates. You introduced an arbitrary "v" as a placeholder holder for "not given" which is the reason for your problems.
None of your problems exist, and it is also much cleaner style if it possible to not have a name or age.

```
stu_name(123,"steve").
stu_age(123,42).
% it is not possible to have the same ID but different names
:- stu_name(ID,Name1), stu_name(ID,Name2), Name1 != Name2.
% it is not possible to have the same ID but different ages
:- stu_age(ID,Age1), stu_age(ID,Age2), Age1 != Age2.
```

Seperating name and age allows you to not have one of the two entries. When you use the ternary stu(ID,Name,Age) predicate you actually always have to give a Name AND and age ("v" isnt something magical, it will be interpreted as name or age)

To avoid several studens with the same id, you could write:

```
stu(123,"Anne",30).
stu(123,"Mia",14).
% it is not possible to have the same ID but not completely equal entries
:- stu(ID,Name1,Age1), stu(ID,Name2,Age2), (Name1,Age1)!=(Name2,Age2).
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and I've rephrased my second problem. I know the problem is a little strange and hope I can make it clear this time.

Comment: I tried to express what you want, and I guess that you mean some kind of database key feature, like uniqueness of ID.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to express, thanks for your answer, it really helps a lot!